# Mock requestAnimationFrame in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following code in my web app:

```
  const scroll = () => {
    const scrollPerTick = (amountToScroll / 200) * 12;
      if (scrolled < amountToScroll) {
        container.scrollBy(0, scrollPerTick);
      }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => scroll(scrollBy));
  };

if (scrolled < amountToScroll) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
}
```

When I run `Jest`, this code is not covered because `requestAnimationFrame` is not executed by Jest, though it doesn't throw any error. I tried mocking `requestAnimationFrame` by putting following code in my test file, as described [here](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html):

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const { window } = jsdom;

function copyProps(src, target) {
  Object.defineProperties(target, {
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(src),
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(target),
  });
}

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js',
};
global.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback) {
  return setTimeout(callback, 0);
};
global.cancelAnimationFrame = function (id) {
  clearTimeout(id);
};
copyProps(window, global);
```

But it didn't work. Is there any way to mock `requestanimationFrame` in my tests?

Comment: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/mock-raf/blob/master/README.md could this help? If nothing else, to provide a direction to head in?

Comment: In Jest JSDOM environment `global === window`, copyProps doesn't serve a good purpose. Yes, you can try to mock it with setTimeout. It's unknown under which circumstances you use it. It's not a good idea to test things like this one in Jest. it doesn't behave like a browser. Elements have zero sizes. Could be a reason why scroll doesn't work where it should.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were on the right track... change your `global.requestAnimationFrame` line to:

```js
        Object.defineProperty(window, "requestAnimationFrame", {
          writable: true,
          value: callback => callback()
        });
```